# Sci-fi / horror / weird story collection - opal miner loses his pupils - man goes astral projecting comes back to corpse - doppelganger story also

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

trying to find a (weird fiction / science fiction / horror) short story collection I read as a child - seem to remember it being hardcover, quite large and square-ish - some of the stories I remember:

- An opal gatherer or miner has a meeting with aliens, and what comes back doesn't have any pupils (or possibly irises)?
- A man learns to astral project but goes away so long people think he's dead and they bury him and he comes back trapped in his rotting corpse
- Something about doppelgangers?

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you sure about the opal part? Just checking because opal eliminates almost every potential result.

Comment: @Hack-R - thought I was sure about opals but mis-remembered something else I was "sure" of another question some please, if you've got any potentials, chuck them at me :)